# Broken tag progress [reactjs]

Tags: support, tags

All of my tag progress seems to be working fine, however the [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag has no progress when I view my profile. It shows up as 0 score & 0 answers

I do have a couple of answers in this tag, and I thought it might be one of my top tags.

Is this a bug or something? what can be done to fix this? Anyone else experiences the same thing?

Comment: You have only [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55236329/4642212) of a score other than 0 which was upvoted 7 hours ago. The tag progress probably just didn’t update yet. It doesn’t update immediately.

Comment: You didn't have any answers in [reactjs], only questions.  The one answer you posted today (not a couple) is going to take up to 24 hours to get merged into the profile statistics.

Comment: okay question score doesn't count towards tag score, thanks